# Resource leak test

Tags: java, memory-leaks, fileinputstream, resource-leak

I'm trying to understand how not calling close() on any streams can affect the performance and functionality of a system. In order to do that I created the below test class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      int loopCount = 1000000;
      for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:/files/the-file-name" + i +".txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("The first line");
        writer.println("The second line");
        writer.close();
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/files/the-file-name" + i +".txt");
    }
}
```

I was monitoring this program using VisialVM. I could see the GC performing properly. No mem leaks as expected.

**BUT** Then I thought at least I should see some exceptions because I'm basically **exhausting the available file descriptors** available to my java process. Why there is no exception here ? The program keeps running!

Another issue is, although I have a FileInputStream for every new file created, if I go and try to delete any of the files, there is no lock on the OS side to prevent me.

Could anyone explain if my test is valid or not?
And please explain about resource leak in case of failure to call close on any streams.

Comment: Try keeping all of the references from being GC'd (eg: add them to an `ArrayList` and see if your performance changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most streams have a `finalize()` method which will close them up for you, so in this code the streams can be GC'd and closed automatically as the variable falls out of scope during each iteration of the loop.

This doesn't mean that you shouldn't be careful about releasing resources. It's just a safety.